# NewtonSoft Json Assembly version issues

Tags: .net, json.net

I am getting an error with NewtonSoft JSON when I try to build my application.

```
Error   4   Assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Did you solve this error? I'm stuck in the same situation and the answers given so far don't help.

Answer (score 10):

Change your project to reference to JSON.NET version 6 since you use another dependency (`System.Web.Http`) that needs it. You can't use two versions of the same assembly in one project.

You can get the latest version (6) using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Run this in your package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Answer (score 0):

from Nuget package manager you can install specific version of dll

Answer (score 0):

All I did was edited the csproj file, by identifying the versions there were two versions of NewtonSoft I removed one of the version from the csproj and saved the file. It got fixed.